# Implementing if-else condition inside ajax script

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having a problem with this condition. The "(numofeggs < totalsm)" in the condition is only executes. Otherwise, all variables (except "numofeggs < totalsm") are not functional. Is there any ways things to do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  displayDataSM();
  displayTotaleggs();
  $("#btn-input").click(function() {
    var numofeggs = $("#numofeggs").val();
    var size = $("#size").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var farmername = $("#farmername").val();
    var totalsm = "<?php echo $totalSmall ?>";

    if ((numofeggs < totalsm) && (size && price && farmername)) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxeggsout.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {
          "btn-input": 1,
          "numofeggs": numofeggs,
          "size": size,
          "price": price,
          "farmername": farmername
        },
        success: function(data) {
          displayDataSM();
          displayTotaleggs();
          $("#numofeggs").val('');
        }
      })
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: if((numofeggs < totalsm) && (size && price && farmername))

Shouldn't this be written as

if((numofeggs < totalsm) && (size > 0  && price > 0 && farmername.length > 0 ))

Comment: From my program, (numoffeggs<totalsm) only excutes. Your suggestion stops working...

Comment: @Satya `0` and `""` are falsy values in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your inputs to numbers. The number `0` is falsy, but the string `"0"` is truthy. And when you do comparison with `<`, numbers work differently than strings (e.g. `5 < 12` is true, but `"5" < "12"` is false).

For the inputs, use `Number()` to convert them to numbers. And for the variable that comes from PHP, don't put it in quotes.

So do:

```
var numofeggs = Number($("#numofeggs").val());
var size = Number($("#size").val());
var price = Number($("#price").val());
var farmername = $("#farmername").val();
var totalsm = <?php echo $totalSmall ?>;
```

Comment: When I remove less than "<" sign, It's working. But the condition of (numofeggs < totalsm) is still I need to...

Comment: Where should I put this condition (numofeggs < totalsm)? In the last part?

Comment: See my updated answer, you need to convert more things to numbers.

Comment: My first program: if(numofeggs && size && price  && farmername), is all working when I execute button.

My second program: if((numofeggs < totalsm) && (size && price  && farmername)), the "size", "price", and "farmername" are not working anymore

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the value of all the variables?